# How do I set the size of messages in Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm currently using Kafka 0.9.0.1. According to some sources I've found, the way to set the sizes of messages is to modify the following key values in `server.properties`.

- message.max.bytes
- replica.fetch.max.bytes
- fetch.message.max.bytes

My `server.properties` file actually has these settings.

```
message.max.bytes=10485760
replica.fetch.max.bytes=20971520
fetch.message.max.bytes=10485760
```

Other settings that may be relevant are below.

```
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
```

However, when I attempt to send messages with payloads of 4 to 6 MB in size, the consumer never gets any messages. The producer seems to send the messages without any exceptions being thrown. If I do send smaller payloads (like < 1 MB) then the consumer does actually receive the messages.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong in terms of configuration settings?

Here is the example code to send a message.

```
Producer<String, byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(getProducerProps());
File dir = new File("/path/to/dir");
for(String s : dir.list()) {
  File f = new File(dir, s);
  byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath());
  Payload payload = new Payload(data); //a simple pojo to store payload
  String key = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
  byte[] val = KryoUtil.toBytes(payload); //custom util to use kryo to get bytes[]
  producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test", key, val));
}
producer.close();
```

Here is the example code to receive a message.

```
KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(getConsumerProps());
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test"));
while(true) {
  ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> records = consumer.poll(100);
  for(ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record : records) {
    long offset = record.offset();
    String key = record.key();
    byte[] val = record.value();
    Payload payload = (Payload)KryoUtil.toObject(val, Payload.class); //custom util to use kryo to deserialize back to object
    System.out.println(
      System.format("offset=%d, key=%s", offset, key));
  }
}
```

Here are the methods to populate the properties files for the producer and consumer.

```
public static Properties getProducerProps() {
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "qc1:9092,qc2:9092,qc3:9092,qc4:9092");
  props.put("acks", "all");
  props.put("retries", 0);
  props.put("batch.size", 16384);
  props.put("linger.ms", 1);
  props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
  props.put("compression.type", "snappy");
  props.put("max.request.size", 10485760); //need this
  props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
  props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
  return props;
}

public static Properties getConsumerProps() {
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "qc1:9092,qc2:9092,qc3:9092,qc4:9092");
  props.put("group.id", "test");
  props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
  props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
  props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
  props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", 10485760); //need this too
  props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
  props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
  return props;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jane,
Don't use `fetch.message.max.bytes` first of all because that's a property that is from the consumer and doesn't go in the server.properties file and second because is for the old version of the consumer, instead 
use `max.partition.fetch.bytes` when you create the Consumer as part of the properties that you use to instantiate it.

Comment: I just tried that, but I get the same effect. "Large" files are not being received. I'm wondering if they are even being sent, because when the consumer starts reading from the topic, the offsets are contiguous (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc...). To me, it seems that the producer may not even be sending the large files?

Comment: It turns out that I need to set both `max.request.size` for the producer and `max.partition.fetch.bytes` for the consumer. I'll tinker a bit with the code to see if `max.partition.fetch.bytes` is really needed.

Comment: Yes, it turns out I do need both settings. If I do not set `max.partition.fetch.bytes`, then I get a `RecordTooLargeException`.

Comment: Yes, you are going to need max.request.size also, but since you told me that sending wasn't a problem I didn't pay much attention to that parameter. Can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase in server (as already described) and client side.

Example in Python using kafka-python Producer:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=brokers, max_request_size=1048576)
```

Increase max_request_size to desired value, default is 1048576.

Answer (score 0):

The max.fetch.bytes option is also possible.